# Yii framework - picking up field value from other model

Tags: yii

I have been struggling with this, i have two models and showing data in Cgridview with one model, this model contains some id's whose values are in different table

So, i have added

'value'=> 'TblAreaoflaw::model()->FindByPk($data->typeoflaw)->areaoflaw'

which is giving this error

"Trying to get property of non-object"

Might be due to this reason that the some records doesn't exist in the TblAreaoflaw. Can't we check in this line through isset?

When i put static value, it work well, like

'value'=> 'TblAreaoflaw::model()->FindByPk(5)->areaoflaw',

Could anyone please help

thanks a lot

Comment: Larry Ullman is the person who can help you in YII

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because this expression `TblAreaoflaw::model()->FindByPk($data->typeoflaw)` is returning `null`. This means that you are effectively trying to get `null->areaoflaw` which won't work (this is what the error message *"Trying to get property of non-object"* clarifies).

My best guess is that `$data->typeoflaw` returns a non-existing primary key for the TblAreaoflaw model.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure :

TblAreaoflaw is actually a model, I doubt its **Areaoflaw**

You have database specified primary key which is the **id** (5) you are passing

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 'value'=> '(TblAreaoflaw::model()->FindByPk($data->typeoflaw)->areaoflaw) ?
 : "default or null value"'
```

Obviously substitute the null string to whatever you want. You may need to adjust the condition to use !empty() or similar, but see how it goes. (And if you do that or aren't using PHP 5.3, use the full ternary expression.)