# CGridView Filter Multiple Models

Tags: php, view, grid, yii

I have searched and searched for an answer to my problem but neither of them worked. My problem is regarding the filtering/searching in the CGridView for Yii.

In my Applicant model I have the following:

```
private $_city = null;
private $province_id = null;
public function getCity()
    {
        if($this->_city === null && $this->address_id !== null) {
            $this->_city = $this->address->city;
        }

        return $this->_city;
    }

    public function setCity($value)
    {
        $this->_city = $value;
    }

public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->with = array('address'=>array('alias'=>'address'));

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('phn',$this->phn);
        $criteria->compare('gender',$this->gender);
        $criteria->compare('dob',$this->dob,true);
        $criteria->compare('first_name',$this->first_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('last_name',$this->last_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('band_id',$this->band_id);
        $criteria->compare('note',$this->note,true);
        $criteria->compare('address.city',$this->city);
        $criteria->compare('address.province_id',$this->province_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'attributes'=>array(
                    'id',
                    'phn',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'band_id',
                    'city'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'address.city ASC',
                        'desc'=>'address.city DESC',
                    ),
                    'province_id'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'address.province_id ASC',
                        'desc'=>'address.province_id DESC',
                    ),
                )
            )
        ));
    }
```

In my View I have

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'applicants-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phn',
            array(
                'name'=>'band_id',
                'value'=>'$data->band->name',
                'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Band::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'city',
                'value'=>'$data->address->city', // causes 'Trying to get property of non-object' - no error if $data->city
                'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Address::model()->findAll(), 'city', 'city'),
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                'template'=>'{view}',
                'buttons'=>array(
                    'view'=>array(
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/applicant/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    ));
```

I have the cities and drop down list showing but when I choose are city from the dropdown it does not filter the widget with the proper results.

I have tried doing the solutions in the following pages

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/11546-cgridview-with-mulitple-model/ 
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/19913-cgridview-with-multiple-models/

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching on the primary key of the city table in your compare statement?

E.g., if the PK of city is "city_id" you would need to change the lines below in your model and view, respectively:

```
$criteria->compare('address.city_id',$this->city);

'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Address::model()->findAll(), 'city_id', 'city')
```

(In this example you would leave "city" as the name so it displays as text in the grid, but specify the PK, city_id, in the listData in the value attribute.)

Comment: No. I'm just trying to filter the cities. There's not lookup table for the city since the user can put any city they want so I the dropdown list is a list of the cities that the users have entered.

Comment: Well then I would use Firebug or similar to make sure the right data is getting passed and that there are no JS errors. If the city names are getting into the list ok, then your relation would seem to be ok there, but it's not clear if you are still getting errors as per the php comment. You could also turn on query logging or use MySql log to get some insight as to what the query is trying to do.

Comment: Also, if it's an issue of the city fields sometimes being blank, you could see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775347/yii-framework-picking-up-field-value-from-other-model for how to structure the value.

Comment: some city fields can be blank. I shall look into firebug next time i work on it again. thanks for the help.